# get error when use cloudboost js sdk for user logout function, any idea?

Tags: cloudboost

```
CB.CloudUser.current.logOut({

     success: function(user) {

},
     error: function(err) {

})(here shows ',' expected);
```

Comment: We need the code you've written to answer this question. Can you please update this question with the code?

Comment: Hi, Nawaz, I just figure it out, i missing the brack, after I compare the sample code you guys provides for ionic.

Comment: We'll fix this. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a bracket in your JS code. :)